# What is "star rating" of a publication?

Tags: tenure-track, united-kingdom

As a part of a (UK) lecturer position, one reads as follows.

> Innovation and impact:
>
> Examples of Innovation and Impact would be: Contribution to knowledge
>
> - Publication (please state **star rating**), presentation and performance or exhibitions.

I googled the term "star rating" but I didn't get what it really is. Any clues about it?

Comment: I suspect, but am not sure, that this is a reference to the ratings given to research publications during the REF evaluations. Where did you see this description? Is it at your place of work, or part of something that was sent to you?

Comment: @YemonChoi: "Where did you see this description?": As the question states, in one of the application forms of the job I am applying for. "Is it at your place of work": No, I don't work there.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Your question did not mention job applications; I thought that perhaps you were reading the internal specification for e.g. promotion criteria

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless there is some parallel system specific to the field (they do exist i believe), this is almost certainly a reference to the Research Excellence Framework (REF). https://www.ref.ac.uk/

In brief, every 5 years every department in the UK must submit (2.5 times number of staff) outputs (papers/books etc) for assessment. Every staff member must be an author on at least 1 and no more than 4 outputs. The papers are then graded 1*, 2*, 3* or 4* by a panel of experts in the relevant field. Departments then receive some amount of government funding based on the results (this accounts for 10%-20% of income at my institution).

I have to say, i have no idea how you are supposed to know the rating of your papers, particularly if you are just applying for your first lectureship. Some universities run mock REFs to see how they are doing, and judge which papers to submit. But you wouldn't be involved with that unless you were already a faculty member. They must be asking you to estimate. Your best bet is probably to ask a colleague in your discipline who is familiar with ref.

As a rough guide, 4* is "world leading", and generally refers to papers in generalist journals (Nature/Science/NEMJ et al), papers in the sub journals from the same publishers (e.g. Nature Genetics etc) or the very top disciplinary journals (in my field, genomics, something in "Genome Research" would probably be judged low 4 or high 3).

3* is "internationally excellent", and is generally given for work which is important to the field, but maybe not so recognised outside the field. Think second tear generalist journals (PNAS, BMJ, JAMA etc), or good displinary journals.

2* is "internationally recognised"

1* is "nationally recognised".

Its the number of 3 or 4* papers that decides funding, so in general, universities only care about papers they think will be judged 3* or above.

Comment: 'i have no idea how you are supposed to know the rating of your papers'  An identical requirement appears in [this job advertisement](https://staff.napier.ac.uk/services/hr/recruitmentandselection/Job_description_repository/jobdescriptions/Interview%20Pack%20-%20Midwifery%20(1).pdf), which provides a sample answer that may give some clues.  (Although the sample answer has one glaring problem - it claims a review paper has potential to be REF 3* or 4*, whereas IIRC, review papers are not eligible for REF.)

Comment: I contacted the reference of the position, and he stated: "The star rating refers to the U.K. REF - research excellence framework star rating. In a simpler sense, papers that are published in top journals (e.g. 1st quartile according to the Web of Science, Scimago ranking) and which have high citation impact and some deep insight are 4 star papers, other papers in top journals and conferences and also good papers from 2nd quartile journals are typically considered 3 star papers, other papers in 2nd and 3rd quartile journals and not so top and not so selective conferences are ... (to be cont.)"

Comment: "... considered 2star papers, and other published papers that are not in selective journals or conferences are considered 1 star papers or 0star papers."

Comment: I think the definition of rating will be field dependent. For example, going by "1st quartile according to Scimago" every paper i've ever published would be 4*m but thats definitely not who our internal REF mock ranked my papers.

Comment: To complete the information, the statement of the reference above attributes to an engineering position.